# Remove non alphanumeric characters from lastword of a line using regex

Tags: regex

I have two word lines (separated using space). Each word can contain alphanumeric, symbols and punctuations. I need to remove all non-alphanumeric characters from 2nd word, e.g.

Change,

```
AT&T AT&T
```

to :

```
AT&T ATT
```

How can I achieve this using regex pattern replace?

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Comment: @anubhava I am using a 3rd party product implemented using Java. Product uses java for regular expression pattern match. I have tried \s(.+)$ which returns last word, i just dont know how to retain 1st word as is and remove non-alphanumeric characters from 2nd word.

Comment: ok provided an answer below, which should work for Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search for this regex:

```
(\S+\s+)|\W+
```

And replace it by:

```
$1
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/uL2aC5/1)

Answer (score 0):

`[^a-zA-Z0-9]` matches non-alphanumeric. just replace it with empty string.

Comment: I want to replace 2nd word. Input is entire line, e.g. "AT&T AT&T", and I want to convert it to "AT&T ATT".